# How to get list item to fill parent un-ordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to make the list items in my un-ordered list fill the entire list. Because I have one list item that is two words, it is making the ul larger, but the others do not fill the space and I can only roll over and see the 2nd ul and am not able to get my mouse to access those buttons.

Here is the HTML

```
        <div id="body_left_nav"> 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Property Management</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Multi-Family</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Brokerage</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Multi-Family</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Leasing</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Consulting</a> 
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Multi-Family</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

And the CSS

```
#body_left_nav{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
#body_left_nav a { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #000; 
    font-size: 14px;
}
#body_left_nav  ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #004A65 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #004A65 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C4DAE8 0%,#004A65 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
#body_left_nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
#body_left_nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;    
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C4DAE8 0%,#004A65 40%);
}
#body_left_nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#body_left_nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}
#body_left_nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
#body_left_nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    top: 100%;
}
#body_left_nav ul:after {
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}
#body_left_nav ul ul {
    width: 25%;
    background: #5f6975; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: absolute; 
    display: none;
}
#body_left_nav ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none; 
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #004A65 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #004A65 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C4DAE8 0%,#004A65 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-top: 1px solid #D32026;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D32026;
    position: relative;
}
#body_left_nav ul ul li a {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

EDIT: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bv9j8ra5/
I don't know why the whole navigation and the ul ul are indented. It doesn't do that on my site but I still have the problem with the list item not filling the parent ul.

EDIT: This also might help. Here is an image of whats happening. I don't have a gap on "Property Management", but I have one on the other 3. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbDnW.png

Comment: please create a jsfiddle to easily demonstrate the scenario.

Comment: check this link[http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/bv9j8ra5/8/ ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you need to remove the margin and padding from the nested ul.

```
#body_left_nav ul ul {
    width: 25%;
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
```

**EDIT:**

There are several approaches on this, you can do it statically with padding.
Here is the applicable CSS:

```
#body_left_nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
}
#body_left_nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.2em 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bv9j8ra5/3/

**EDIT #2:**

Or you can do it dynamically with relative positioning.

CSS:

```
#body_left_nav ul li {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        height: 50px;
}
#body_left_nav ul li a {
    display: block; 
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bv9j8ra5/5/

Comment: hmmm. If you scrunch the nav bar to where "property management" are on two lines, I'm still not able to get my mouse to hover onto Brokerage, Leasing, or Consulting sub ul's

Comment: It's because you have no height defined and are relying on padding. When the nav moves to the second line, it breaks the height. I would suggest setting a height on the parent `ul` so you can control it. Please see my edit.

Comment: AH! Makes sense now! Now if only the text vertical aligned itself to the middle... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

[live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9j8ra5/1/) or 
[full view Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9j8ra5/1/embedded/result/)

You just need a reset

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Full code

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;margin:0;}
#body_left_nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#body_left_nav a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#body_left_nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: #efefef;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #004A65 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #004A65 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C4DAE8 0%, #004A65 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
#body_left_nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
#body_left_nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C4DAE8 0%, #004A65 40%);
}
#body_left_nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#body_left_nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}
#body_left_nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
#body_left_nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    top: 100%;
}
#body_left_nav ul:after {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
#body_left_nav ul ul {
    width: 25%;
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
#body_left_nav ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    background: #efefef;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #004A65 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #004A65 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C4DAE8 0%, #004A65 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-top: 1px solid #D32026;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D32026;
    position: relative;
}
#body_left_nav ul ul li a {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="body_left_nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Property Management</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Commercial</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Multi-Family</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Brokerage</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Commercial</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Multi-Family</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Leasing</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Commercial</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Consulting</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Commercial</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Multi-Family</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```